# Increment Button in WEB Excel, using Macros

Tags: excel

I want to create a button in WEB EXCEL, which will add 1 to cell A1.
Thus, in cell A1, every time I press the button it will add up with 1. Click A1=1, Click A1=2, Click A1=3 ....

I tried a script from a YouTube video, but it is for Excel 2016(downloadable version).

```
Sub Incr()
Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value + 1
End SUb
```

So it didn't work
I want a script for WEB EXCEL

Answer (score 0):

As of today you can't use VBA macros in web excel: [Work with VBA macros in Excel for the web](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/work-with-vba-macros-in-excel-for-the-web-98784ad0-898c-43aa-a1da-4f0fb5014343)